# Menu toggle bar works only on some pages in WordPress

Tags: css, mobile, responsive, buttons

I'm using a custom WordPress theme extended from Twenty Sixteen for this website. It is using Bootstrap (I had to migrate a static Bootstrap website to WordPress).

If you open the website **on mobile**, only the **homepage menu button works correctly**. However, if you navigate to **any other page, the menu button does not drop down**. I am using the same template (index.php) for the homepage and all other pages. The HTML, CSS code in "Inspect element" looks the same, and the JavaScript files are also the same.

If it's working on the homepage, I can't figure out why it isn't working on the other pages. Here's the link to the WordPress website: https://www.unityinfinity.com/ui

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Where's the homepage menu button (http://prntscr.com/mpq9vd)? And where are those other pages? I can't see any other pages than the homepage. And there's a Google maps javascript error, need to be fixed.

Comment: Check now. I was doing some testing so I switched my theme to a temporary one.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently, the issue was arising due to **Revolution Slider** for some reason. I went into **Revolution Slider -> Global Settings** and turned on the option to allow Revolution Slider libraries to load on all pages, and now the menu toggle works correctly everywhere.

I don't know why it worked, but this seems to be the issue. If someone can help figure out why this works, I'd be grateful!

Comment: Yes, I can see the menu is working perfectly: http://prntscr.com/mq5ujr. Always consult the basic debugging techniques while debugging WordPress: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/debug/info